# Erro ao fazer Upload de arquivo para o banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, arquivo, upload, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer um upload de arquivo para o banco de dados. Só que ao invés de ele mandar o arquivo em si, ele esta mandando o local temporário dele.

Meu código esta assim:

```
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];
$name = $arquivo['name'];
$file_tmp = $arquivo['tmp_name'];
$file_bin = mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($file_tmp));


$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'files');
$sql = "INSERT INTO malote_arq (arquivo, nome) VALUES('$file_bin', '$name')";

mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Daí quando vou lo no banco e resgato o conteúdo do campo *arquivo* ele mostra isso: **C:wamp    mpphpF1F2.tmp**

Comment: Por favor, posta o argumento de file_get_contents

Comment: Amigo funcionou do nada, não sei como....

Comment: coloca o código correto, por favor. Edita e pergunte e por baixo coloca o código que funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque é apena o nome temporário do arquivo e não um caminho(path) para o arquivo. Por isso antes deve saber onde o seu servidor guarda os arquivos temporários e adicionar o caminho para esse ficheiro e adicionar. Qualquer coisa como isto

```
 file_get_contents(/path/folder/temp/nome_do_arquivo);//este é um caminho inventado
```

Se não tiver como saber o caminho, grave o aquivo temporario em qualquer lugar que saiba depois passar como argumento para file_get_contents

Pode encontrar o directorio no php.info() em upload_tmp_dir.

Comment: Ainda sem sucesso amigo, ele continua mandando o mesmo nome que citei acima